# How to disable webbrowser security warning in WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, security, wpf-controls, browser

I am using webbrowser control in my WPF application using VS 2010 (C#). and I am displaying a local html with js file in my webbrowser. and it displaying the security warning. So can anyone suggest how can i disable this security warning.[image]

After adding the below line:

```
"<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->"
```

It display below error:
[image]

Comment: Probably you have to change the security policy

Comment: @Grumber: That's using a global solution to fix a local problem.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add [mark of the web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to you local HTML. Add following to very beginning of you HTML file:

```
  <!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. I already tried this. but it change the alert display type only. I have updated the my question for this.

Answer (score 3):

The local host and code 16 from the other answer didn't work for me; however I think there must be a newer solution as this following version on the first line of HTML before  worked for me. This is VS 2013 for reference.

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to load html file using system path and mark of the web wasn't enough. So besides

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

as a first line in my html file I also had to transform my path to html file (C:\somedir\somefile.html) into

```
file://127.0.0.1/c$/somedir/somefile.html
```

code example:

```
string somePath = @"C:\somedir\somefile.html".Replace(@"C:\", "file://127.0.0.1/c$/");
```